# Python - How I pass a vector in where condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python Data Science. Did work in R and exploring Python for ML.
I used pass vector in R where condions but I am not sure how I do that in Python.

```
raw_data1 = {'age1': [23,45,21],'age2': [10,20,50], 'age3':[44,55,77]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data1, columns = ['age1','age2','age3'])

raw_data2 = {'age1': [23,45]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data2, columns = ['age1'])
```

Here I like to query df1 based on df2-age1 vector. I tried below but didn't work

```
df3 = df1.iloc[np.where(df1.age1 == df2['age1'])]
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: `df1[df1.age1.isin(df2.age1)]`

Comment: Try adding parenthesis between each part of your condition: `(df1.age1) == (df2.age1)`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thank you. It is working. BTW, how I deal with if my varaibles are in text (not numbers). I tried with same syntax but didn't work.

Comment: @COLDSPEED It is working for both numbers and strings. Thank you